# tmux did not come pre-installed on Mac OS Catalina

Tags: macos, tmux

tmux did not come installed on Mac OS, specifically Mac OS Catalina. Is this something that is supposed to come pre-installed similar to Vim?

I was expecting it to come installed since it was mentioned in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeOSpnT29go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tmux is not part of macOS.
You need to install it through homebrew.

```
$ brew install tmux
```

There are some beginner's usage instructions on [Medium - Install tmux on OSX and Basics Commands for Beginners](https://medium.com/@jeongwhanchoi/install-tmux-on-osx-and-basics-commands-for-beginners-be22520fd95e)